# Knockout-Kendo.js DatePicker / WebAPI / ISO 8601 Date binding

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, iso8601

I'm having troubles with the ISO 8601 format as generated from the ASP.NET WebAPI and binding to the KendoUI DatePicker widget using Knockout-Kendo.js.

References:

```
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.common.min.css
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.default.min.css 
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.core.min.js
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.web.min.js
    http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js
    http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/js/knockout-kendo.min.js
```

Html:

```
    <span data-bind="text: bigday"></span><br />
    <input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: bigday" />
```

Javascript:

```
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.bigday = ko.observable("2013-06-01T00:00:00"); 
        // ISO 8601 date as returned from ASP.NET WebAPI
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bschafer/NGLEp/

For some reason the value is not binding to the KendoDatePicker but it is binding to the span w/o a problem.

Comment: In the end, I went with the following for the binding.

data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: bigday, parseFormats: ['yyyy-MM-dd'] } "

This allowed the control to adjust the display based on locale automatically.  I've updated the fiddle.

Thank you for the help nemesv!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kendo.UI DatePicker uses the [following default date time format](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker#format-stringdefault): `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt`

So you just need to change it with the `format` option:

```
<input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: bigday, format: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ye865/).

Note that there is also a [parseFormats](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker#parseformats-array) which you can use if you want to parse your dates in one format but display them in a different format.

Comment: Thanks for helping out a noob! :)